# Горизонтальный сепаратов в GridView

Tags: android, gridview

У меня есть `ArrayList` некоторых объектов. `ArrayList` включает в себя несколько категоруй объектов (`cat 1, cat 2, cat 3, ...`). И я хочу отображать мой лит в `GridView`.

Мой `xml` выглядит так:

```
 <GridView
                android:id="@+id/gv_my_grid"
                style="@style/fill_wrap"
                android:cacheColorHint="@null"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                android:numColumns="3"
                android:listSelector="@android:color/transparent"
                android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
                android:gravity="center"
                />
```

И все работает отлично

`GridView` выглядит так:

```
|item 1 (cat 1)| |item 2 (cat 1)| |item 3 (cat 1)|
|item 4 (cat 1)| |item 5 (cat 2)| |item 6 (cat 2)|
|item 7 (cat 3)| |item 8 (cat 3)| |item 9 (cat 3)|
```

Но сейчас я хочу вставлять горизонтальный сепаратор между элементами различных категорий.
И это должно выглядеть так:

```
___________category_1_____________________________
|item 1 (cat 1)| |item 2 (cat 1)| |item 3 (cat 1)|
|item 4 (cat 1)| 
___________category_2_____________________________
|item 5 (cat 2)| |item 6 (cat 2)|
___________category_1_____________________________
|item 7 (cat 3)| |item 8 (cat 3)| |item 9 (cat 3)|
```

Возможно ли это, тк все что нашел - имплементации для `ListView`.

Answer (score 1):

Юзайте [StikyGridHeaders](https://github.com/TonicArtos/StickyGridHeaders)